# How can I express that two array indexes also equal to either one of the values in a conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

in Javascript, how can I express that if array1[i] and array2[j] also equal to either "0", "O" or "Q", then array1[i] is equal to array2[j]? I have tried multiple ways but it didn't work. Thanks.

```
if ((array1[i] == "0" || "O" || "Q") && (array2[j] == "0" || "O" || "Q")){
          array1[i] == array2[j];
}
```

or

```
if ((array1[i] && array2[j]) == "0" || "O" || "Q"){
              array1[i] == array2[j];
}
```

Comment: your first code is correct but change  array1[i] == array2[j]; to  array1[i] = array2[j]; with single equal sign. double equal and triple equal signs are for compression. single equal sign is for assignment like assigning value in array to array 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another array to check whether it includes value of array[i]

```js
const oArr = ["0", "O", "Q"]
if (oArr.includes(array1[i]) && oArr.includes(array2[j])) {
  console.log("They both have 0, O or Q")
}
```